# C# and Access query issue

Tags: c#, sql

I have a quick question about insert queries in C#. I'm trying to create an application which will allow a student to enrol/register for optional classes/modules. so what I've done is create dynamic controls which will list all the modules and optional modules, the modules that are optional have a button which will allow the student to enrol, here is where I'm running into some trouble. I have created an insert query which will insert the studentID, CourseID, year and moduleID into the database but the problem is I'm not using user input such as textboxes, Ideally I want the user to be able to click the enrol button for a module and have the information inserted into the database but for that to work the moduleID for each course must be different and I'm wondering how to go about getting the moduleID. I will illustrate my problem below to make it more clear. Let's say the student has enrolled in a Computer Science course and they've benn asked to select some optional modules, they may have a list like this:

Computer Science:

C++ Programming (Required)

Java Programming (Required)

Database Design (Optional) [Enrol button]

OOP1 (Required)

Design Patterns (Optional) [Enrol Button]

Here the user can sign up for either Database Design or Design Patterns (they may even choose both) however, each module will have a different ModuleID which I need to be able to insert when the button is clicked.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Regards

-Joshmond

Answer (score 0):

Oki from what i understand , your DB design need to have 3 different tables.
1- Student.
2- Model.
3- StudentModels.

The "StudentModels" table is your M:M relation table, whenever the user or the student select a Model, you add the ModelID & StudentID to it as new recored.

hope this help.

Comment: I have done this, my database has the three tables and I'm selecting the data from them, with the studentID and the courseID they are static and are easy to insert, the problem is the ModuleID as it varies. In my code I am generating labels and buttons and runtime and what I want to do essentially is map the MouleID onto a label, so each label will have a diiferent ID, so let's "Database Design" has an ID of 2 and "Design Patterns" has an ID of 4, when the student enrols on either module it should insert either "2" or "4" as the ModuleID

Comment: oki, am confused, is your issue on an UI level or DB !?
if DB , then add another Table for StudentModel, which hold All Student model regardless the course. 
ill suggest using MVC approach if you not !

Comment: The database information is all there but I'm wondering how to access the moduleID and put that into the insert query, I'll give you an example of how it should look in the database, let's say you enrol for databse design which has the moduleID of 2 let's say then the query being inserted would look like this: StudentID (1234) CourseID (CS04) YearEnrolled (06/05/2017) ModuleID (2). If the Design Patterns class is chosen then the ID would be something else, so the moduleID is dynamic and what I want to do is insert the data into the database without having to type in the ModuleID.

Comment: If you set up the table to auto-increment you should be able to just omit that part and it will do it for you.  Hope that helps.